# Does License change for a user requires IE cache clearing?

Tags: profile, user

I have a user who is assigned **Chatter Only** License and **Profile A** in **production** org.

As part of new requirement, I changed the License and the Profile for that user to **Salesforce** and **Profile B** respectively in **Sandbox** org.

Now, when the user is logging into Sandbox environment, somehow it looks like that the new license is not coming into effect.

Is it required to clear some cache? Or is it something that I missed that needs to be looked into?

Comment: I dont think clearing cache would help you.Please look in the permission set if assigned any.what exactly is the problem you are facing.

Comment: FYI - You CAN change the chatter license to a SF license, you cannot change a SF license to anything else (at least not in my orgs)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change User License in user's profile. Once you convert user from Chatter license type you won't be able to switch it back, and would have to create a new user profile for this user. However, you can flip users from Salesforce to Force.com or other platform license as long as you have them available in your org.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I changed the user license from chatter only to Salesforce for the user by editing that user. But still when this user logs in it looks like that the old license is coming into effect because the sales cloud is not accessible. so I was wondering if I missed anything.

Comment: Well, you have to edit `Profile` that you also have assigned to this user to provide all necessary CRUD setting for the object you want this user to have access to. I recommend to use some of standard profiles first if you want to test access and you can change it any time.